# How do i override the user agent stylesheet (Chrome) to set the overflow to visible for my svg?

Tags: css, svg, google-chrome-devtools

I've been trying to set the overflow of this SVG to visible but the user agent stylesheet keeps overriding it. It's frustrating.

I've set + the overflow to visible  + I used a css code:

```css
background: URL(
<svg width="350" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
      <linearGradient x1="50%" y1=".779%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="c">
        <stop stop-color="#0989B4" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%"/>
        <stop stop-color="#53FFEE" offset="99.94%"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="50%" y1=".779%" x2="50%" y2="100%" id="d">
        <stop stop-color="#0989B4" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%"/>
        <stop stop-color="#53FFEE" offset="99.94%"/>
      </linearGradient><path id="a" d="M0 0h350v140H0z"/>
  </defs>
  <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><mask id="b" fill="#fff">
    <use xlink:href="#a"/>
  </mask>
  <use fill="#41CBD3" xlink:href="#a"/>
  <g mask="url(#b)" opacity=".5">
    <g transform="translate(-11 -4)">
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 60.479 14.8)" cx="60.479" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 14.834 14.8)" cx="14.834" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="151.767" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 106.123 14.8)" cx="106.123" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 243.055 14.8)" cx="243.055" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 197.411 14.8)" cx="197.411" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="334.344" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 288.7 14.8)" cx="288.699" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-11 91.63)">
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 60.479 14.8)" cx="60.479" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 14.834 14.8)" cx="14.834" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="151.767" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/><ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 106.123 14.8)" cx="106.123" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 243.055 14.8)" cx="243.055" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 197.411 14.8)" cx="197.411" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="334.344" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 288.7 14.8)" cx="288.699" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-11 43.815)">
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 60.479 14.8)" cx="60.479" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="14.834" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="151.767" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 106.123 14.8)" cx="106.123" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 243.055 14.8)" cx="243.055" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="197.411" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="334.344" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 288.7 14.8)" cx="288.699" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(11.822 18.77)">
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 60.479 14.8)" cx="60.479" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 14.834 14.8)" cx="14.834" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="151.767" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 106.123 14.8)" cx="106.123" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 243.055 14.8)" cx="243.055" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 197.411 14.8)" cx="197.411" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="334.344" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 288.7 14.8)" cx="288.699" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(11.822 114.4)">
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 60.479 14.8)" cx="60.479" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 14.834 14.8)" cx="14.834" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="151.767" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 106.123 14.8)" cx="106.123" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 243.055 14.8)" cx="243.055" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" transform="rotate(180 197.411 14.8)" cx="197.411" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="334.344" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 288.7 14.8)" cx="288.699" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(11.822 66.585)">
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 60.479 14.8)" cx="60.479" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="14.834" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="151.767" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 106.123 14.8)" cx="106.123" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(-90 243.055 14.8)" cx="243.055" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="197.411" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#d)" cx="334.344" cy="14.8" rx="14.834" ry="14.8"/>
      <ellipse fill="url(#c)" transform="rotate(90 288.7 14.8)" cx="288.699" cy="14.8" rx="14.8" ry="14.834"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
   )
```

The link to the website for personal checks is https://efecollins.github.io/pcard/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: set `style="overflow:visible"` for the svg element and remove the mask i.e change `<g mask="url(#b)" opacity=".5">` to `<g opacity=".5">` However there are a lot of improvements to be done. For example you use the same ellipse over and over. You could replace the ellipses with use elements. Also you are grouping 8 ellipses and reuse the group over and over. You can ue a use element instead of the group and translate the use element

Answer (score 0):

You could include this kind of css file : https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ It's made to remove all browser default style.

But in your case, you could add some inline style like `style="overflow:visible"` in your `svg` tag, it will override browser default browser style. A better solution will be to add it to your css

```
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```